# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE In ASP.NET Core Application In Docker Container

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I've read dozens of posts of my issue specifically and tried a million different things but I'm still getting the error message which I can only assume is an issue with ports not being published. This being said, I believe I'm doing everything to publish those ports.

I created an ASP.NET Core application using .NET 7. I didn't change anything, everything is the out-of-the-box template VS provides. My Dockerfile is the following:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTesting/DockerTesting.csproj", "DockerTesting/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTesting/DockerTesting.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTesting"
RUN dotnet build "DockerTesting.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTesting.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTesting.dll"]`
```

When ran from Visual Studio, both in debug and non-debugging mode, it runs fine. When I run it from the command prompt with a command such as:

`docker run -it --rm -p 32789:80 -p 32788:443 -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+" dockertesting:dev`

Or

`docker run -it --rm -p 2376:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443 --name test dockertesting:dev`

Or

`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name test dockertesting:dev`

Nothing works. I just get a response of

`This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`